# camera2 API captured image preview

Tags: android, android-camera

The function onImageAvailable handles the image save, how can it be used to set a preview for the user to review, typically on an ImageView.

```
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            //mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(), mFile));
            Image image = reader.acquireNextImage();
            ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            setPreviewImage(bmp);
        }
```

This does not work for me.

Comment: Please explain what "this does not work for me" means.

Comment: If you just want a preview on the screen, it is highly suggested to have your CameraCaptureSession send the image data directly to a SurfaceView or SurfaceTexture, rather than turning it into a bitmap image and sending it to an ImageView. Is there a reason you want to do it this way?

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you suggest doing something inside the onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session,
      CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) of the CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback? Where do I get the image data from?

Comment: I suggest that you explain what "this does not work for me" means.

Comment: When I try to set the preview image bitmap to the ImageView; setPreviewImage(bmp), it does not show any image at all.

Comment: +rcsumner do you have an example of how do send image data directly ro SurfaceTexture?